# $\forall r>0,j=1,2,\ldots:\mu(\partial B(x_j,r))=0$ for a Borel probability measure $\mu$ over a metric space $X$ where $x_j$ are countably dense

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, separable-spaces, borel-measures

Let $(X, d)$ be a separable metric space and $S:=\{x_1,x_2,\dots,\}$ be a countably dense subset of $X$. Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure of $X$. A proof I am reading states the following which I don't follow:

> For each $j = 1,2,\dots$, the spheres $\partial B(x_j,r)$ are pairwise disjoint. Hence for arbitrarily small $r>0$ it holds that $\mu(\partial B(x_j,r))=0$ for every $j=1,2,\dots$.

What I don't understand is 1.) why are the spheres $\partial B(x_j,r)$ pairwise disjoint for a fixed $r$? If $x_j$ is fixed, then by density of $S$ there exists $x_k\in B(x_j, r/2)\setminus \{x_j\}$ and I do not see how $\partial B(x_j,r)$ and $\partial B(x_k,r)$ are pairwise disjoint. But this might not matter since the proof itself really relies more on the latter claim that

2.) for an arbitrarily small $r>0: \mu(\partial B(x_j,r))=0$. Why is this then true? Is there some cover argument that I just don't see? We only know that $\mu$ is a Borel pr. measure, not that it is shift invariant.

Comment: More context would help, but I think the reading is supposed to be that the spheres are disjoint for each fixed $j$ *as $r$ varies*.  That is, for every $j$ and every $r \ne s$, we have $\partial B(x_j, r) \cap \partial B(x_j, s) = \emptyset$.  And I would have to read the conclusion as "for all $R > 0$ there exists $r< R$ such that for all $j$ we have $\mu(\partial B(x_j, r)) = 0$".

Comment: This would be clear because for each $j$, there are at most countably many $r$ with $\mu(\partial B(x_j ,r)) > 0$.  That is, for each $j$ the set $A_j = \{r : \mu(\partial B(x_j, r)) > 0\}$ is countable.  So $\bigcup_j A_j$ is also countable and hence we can find arbitrarily small values of $r$ that are not in it.

Answer (score 1):

$\partial B(x,r)\subset \{y: d(y,x)=r\}$. From this 1) is obvious.

By 1) you can have at most countably many $r$ for which
$\mu (\partial B(x,r)) >0$. So there exists $r_n$(strictly) decreasing to $0$ such that  $\mu (\partial B(x,r_n)) =0$ for all $n$.

Comment: I still don't understand why 1.) holds: If we have a circle with radius $r$ and centre $x_0$ and draw a new circle with radius $r$ and centre at $x_0 + \epsilon$ with $0 < \epsilon < r$, then how come these two circles do not intersect?

Comment: @CartesianBear Apply my argument to each $x_i$ and note that countable union of countable sets is countable.